# How to know if the device is plugged in using C# and Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am building a game, and would like to know:
How to know if an Android device is plugged-in (i.e. battery is charging) using C# pure code in Unity?

Comment: What device? What do you mean plugged in? Questions here must be as detailed as possible.

Comment: Device = Android. Plugged-in = battery is being charged.

Comment: Did you search for it? Found this: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Device is plugged in:

```
SystemInfo.batteryStatus == BatteryStatus.Charging || SystemInfo.batteryStatus == BatteryStatus.Full || SystemInfo.batteryStatus == BatteryStatus.NotCharging
```

Battery is charging:

```
SystemInfo.batteryStatus == BatteryStatus.Charging
```

Sources:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-batteryStatus.html

> Returns the current status of the device's battery (Read Only).
>
> See the BatteryStatus enumeration for possible values.
>
> **The battery status includes information about whether the device is plugged in to a power source and whether the battery is charging**. If battery status is not available on your target platform, this property returns BatteryStatus.Unknown.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BatteryStatus.html

- Unknown   The device's battery status cannot be determined. If battery status is not available on your target platform, SystemInfo.batteryStatus will return this value.
- **Charging    Device is plugged in and charging.**
- Discharging   Device is unplugged and discharging.
- **NotCharging Device is plugged in, but is not charging.**
- **Full    Device is plugged in and the battery is full.**

Answer (score 2):

In Android, you can use [SystemInfo.batteryStatus](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-batteryStatus.html), checking for the value [BatteryStatus.Charging](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BatteryStatus.Charging.html).
Look here for the other possible status: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BatteryStatus.html